# Word VBA InsertFile syntax

Tags: vba, syntax, ms-word

I'm trying to insert one word file to another word file and it's important that there's also a Link... So I found the option below

`selection.InsertFile(FileName, Range, ConfirmConversions, Link, Attachment)`

But my problem is that I need to add several files (hence using the macro) and I want to choose the file every time myself (not add the directory to the code). Is it somehow possible? I'm not familiar with the VBA syntax.

I could also just use `Dialogs(wdDialogInsertFile).Show` But there I couldn't find a place where turn on the link option.

I hope sb can help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Inputbox ( http://www.functionx.com/vb/functions/inputbox.htm )

```
 FileName = InputBox ("Enter file name")
```

Or even the FileDialog ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163948(v=office.10).aspx )

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .InitialFileName = ""
    .Title = "File Location"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "Word", "*.doc*, 1
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 2

    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        FileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for also adding the links.Thank you so much! :)